# Error: tcl.h not found (no such file or directory)

Tags: files, make, tcl

I'm trying to install something using the 'make' command, however it gives me the fatal error:tcl.h no such file or directory. I'm new to linux, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11):

This means you're missing the tcl development files.  The easiest way to check is to go to: http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and put ["tcl.h" in the "search contents of packages" field](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&mode=exactfilename&arch=any&suite=bionic&keywords=tcl.h).  If you do this you'll find that tcl.h can be found in a number of packages you'll want to install one of those:

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.6-dev
```

Comment: when i use sudo apt-get install tcl8.6-dev, it says: E:Unable to locate package tcl8.6-dev E:Couldn't find any package by regex 'tcl8.6-dev'

Comment: also, it says i have the newest version of tcl8.5-dev

Answer (score 8):

Once you have a Tcl dev package installed, you'll then possibly come across the code expecting tcl.h to be in `/usr/include/`, but in order to facilitate multiple versions of Tcl being installed, Ubuntu places tcl.h in `/usr/include/tcl/` - note the extra directory level.

Replacing: `#include <tcl.h>` with `#include <tcl/tcl.h>` in the source code  you're trying to build should get around this.

Comment: Instead of changing the code, you can change the include path of the compiler: add the option "-I/usr/include/tcl" to the compilation.

Comment: Don't change the code or the compiler flags! Why don't you just install `tcl-dev` package? This one is immediately found as it placs headers in `/usr/include`. :)

Comment: @71GA That may have changed since 20.04 a.k.a Focal (which is what's running on the box I've just check on), but `tcl-dev` on 20.04 placed `tcl.h` in `/usr/include/tcl`. If it had done as you say, I'd not've made my original comment :) 

20.04 creates a symlink:
    ❯ ls -l /usr/include/tcl{,.h}
    ls: cannot access '/usr/include/tcl.h': No such file or directory  
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Feb 23  2019 /usr/include/tcl -> tcl8.6

Gah, no formatting in comments :(

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me, when trying to manually install python3.9 and fixing tinker import error
`Error:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'`

Then, i came to know, when you try to manually configure, you have to pass additional arguments.

```
./configure --with-tcltk-includes="-I/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Headers" --with-tcltk-libs="/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk"
make
```

As, labarna mentioned you can search on ubuntu packages and install those.
Then after that while downloading correct package, it still gave another another.

> gcc -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fvisibility=hidden -I./Include/internal -DWITH_APPINIT=1 -I./Include -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/root/fix/Python-3.9.11/Include -I/root/fix/Python-3.9.11 -c /root/fix/Python-3.9.11/Modules/_tkinter.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/root/fix/Python-3.9.11/Modules/_tkinter.o -I/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Headers
> /root/fix/Python-3.9.11/Modules/_tkinter.c:46:10: fatal error: tk.h: No such file or directory
> 46 | #include <tk.h>
> |          ^~~~~~

As, you can see its expecting package under `/usr/local/include`. And, your download file might be installed to some other location. You have to either copy the required file or create symlink(softlink) to correct directory (for me it was `/usr/local/include`)