# tcl headers not found while installing openSTA

Tags: compiling, cmake, tcl

This is what i get after executing `cmake ..`

```
 - TCL library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcl8.6.so
-- TCL header: TCL_HEADER-NOTFOUND

and after executing "make" 
fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
   19 | #include <tcl.h>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: tcl.h not found (no such file or directory)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366909/error-tcl-h-not-found-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @muru already tried.

Comment: Please note that `opensta-dev` package is in [the repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/opensta-dev) since 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `tcl-dev` worked for me in 16.04 LTS.

```
sudo apt install tcl-dev
```

Comment: sudo apt install tcl-dev
This command also works on ubuntu20.04.Thanks!